# Ajax call and function.apply infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

I'm trying to print a .CSV in a web app I'm building for that purpose I have a link, something simple:

```
<a class="areaSummaryExport" value="1">...</a>
```

Then with Javascript and JQuery I do:

```
$('.areaSummaryExport').on('click', function(){
    exportAreaSummary($(this).attr('value'), $(this));
});
```

To export the .CSV with JQuery I need a `<table>` so I use ajax to get it from the server:

```
function exportAreaSummary(selected, sender){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin_ajax.php',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'exportAreaSummary', area: selected}
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('done');
        exportAreaSummary.apply(this, [data.table, data.name, data.header])
    }).error(function(XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    });
}
```

And when I get it back, I 'apply' this function to create and download it:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename, header) {
    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + 'sep=,' + rowDelim +
        (header? header.join(colDelim) + rowDelim : '') +
        $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td, th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
}
```

This last function works perfectly somewhere else, but there the table is already in the page so I don't have to use any ajax. Here the table shouldn't be in the page, so I'm getting it with ajax and then sending it to `exportTableToCSV()`. But then (I'm not sure why) it goes in an infinite loop until the server crashes (last time there were 2000+ calls to the server).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Any other way to do it will also work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `exportAreaSummary` in the success not `exportTableToCSV`

```
function exportAreaSummary(selected, sender){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin_ajax.php',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'exportAreaSummary', area: selected}
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('done');
        exportTableToCSV($(data.table), data.name, data.header)
    }).error(function(XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, that was a noob mistake.. I guess I was too tired yesterday.. Well, thanks! :D